# Laravel Filament. Отркыть запись для редактирования после ReplicateAction

Tags: laravel

Осваиваю Filament. У меня есть такие действия в ресурсе (копировать и редактировать):

```
->actions([
            Tables\Actions\ReplicateAction::make()
                ->beforeReplicaSaved(
                function (Model $replica): void {
                    $replica->is_current = true;
                    ExchangeRate::query()->where([
                        'base_currency_id' => $replica->base_currency_id,
                        'target_currency_id' => $replica->target_currency_id,
                        'is_current' => true,
                    ])
                        ->update(['is_current' => false]);
                }
            )->after(fn (Model $record) => route('exchange-rates.edit', $record)),
            Tables\Actions\EditAction::make(),
        ])
```

Необходимо в after сделать так, чтобы после копирования записи осуществлялся переход на страницу с редактированием, подобно действию EditAction, как это сделать?

Comment: Попробуйте так `->url(fn (Model $record) => route('exchange-rates.edit', $record));`